# What do I need to change to translate my jQuery find function to mootools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mootools

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#uploadedFiles') // jQuery
.find("input[value='"+searchedValue+"']").each(function(){
    window.alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

How does this translate to Mootools?

Comment: undefined: Somebody else fixed it for me :) (that remained while I was reverting the function from the form I tried to translated)

Comment: Can you please add the `alert` function? Because you'd need to fix that as well.

Comment: @Calvein: I don't have much experience with mootools. I have tried a for to find those (they have recurrent id's) but it does not look as a good solution.

Comment: @TomWijsman: that is a simple javascript alert, I wanted just to see if the value returned is the one I needed.

Comment: @Octavian: There's no such thing as a simple alert, that's the point about it. If you run this outside of the context of a browser there's no `alert` function; and even in browsers, there might not always be an `alert` function either, so if you want to be clear about it you should be calling the right function: [`window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert) Although people prefer [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) for this.

Comment: @TomWijsman In any browser all methods and properties of `window` object are globally defined.

Comment: @VisioN: You're completely missing the point, leaving out `window` makes you assume you're in a scope where `alert` hasn't been redefined, explicitly using `window.alert` tightens that assumption to assume `window` hasn't been redefined. The actual difference between both of them is that linting and hinting surely will occur with the latter, while it is much less likely to occur for the former. Defensive coding... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `uploadedFiles` is an ID of some container:

```
$("uploadedFiles") // MooTools
    .getElements("input[value='" + searchedValue + "']")
    .each(function(el) {
        window.alert(el.id);
    });
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/e4Hbt/